# curl 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Tags: curl, command-line

I am working to setup a curl Command line request. I keep getting the error 'The system cannot find the file specified' when I submit the request. My curl command line statements looks as follows

```
"C:\Program Files\cURL\bin\curl" --verbose -G --compressed --tlsv1 https://xxx.xxx.com/api/v2/search/ -d 'pax=4' -d 'checkout=2015-08-27' -d 'checkin=2015-08-25' -d 'destination_code=19063' -d 'client_nationality=us' -d 'limit=2' --tlsuser xxx --tlspassword xxx  / > curlresponse.json
```

Submitting this immediately generates an error. I don't believe it even attempts to make a connection to the host. The --verbose does not even generate any output.

If I remove the options that pass the username and password (--tlsuser xxx --tlspassword xxx) and update the command line to the following

```
"C:\Program Files\cURL\bin\curl" --verbose -G --compressed --tlsv1 https://xxx.xxx.com/api/v2/search/ -d 'pax=4' -d 'checkout=2015-08-27' -d 'checkin=2015-08-25' -d 'destination_code=19063' -d 'client_nationality=us' -d 'limit=2' / > curlresponse.json
```

The command line does make a connection to the host but is not able to complete the request because of the missing username and password. For that reason it seems like the problem is in how I am passing the username and password. The error I get when I remove the username and password from the command line is {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow. Software questions should be directed to SuperUser.

Comment: curl is not there. why do you think it is?

Answer (score -2):

I came up with command line otpion that looks to be working. Line looks as follows

```
"C:\Program Files\cURL\bin\curl" --verbose -G --compressed --tlsv1 https://xxx.xxx.com/api/v2/search/ -d "pax=4&checkout=2015-08-27&checkin=2015-08-25&destination_code=19063&client_nationality=us&limit=2" --user "xxx:xxx" / > curlresponse.json
```